# presentmodalviewcontroller navigationcontroller

Tags: iphone

I have using an navigation based application, navigation control present in the appdelegate viewcontroller. I have called an uiviewcontroller using presnetmodalviewcontroller. Is there any possible to call another uiviewcontroller using presentmodalviewcontroller with appdelegate's navigationcontrol.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can chain multiple UIViewControllers modally. The [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1) has some example code on how to do it.